# Check route through Slim Middlewhere

Tags: php, slim

I have a route as follows:

```
$app->get('/manager/:page', $authenticate($app), function ($page) use ($app, $secretshibe) {
  $app->render('manager/pages/' . $page . '.php', ['user' => $secretshibe->get_page($page, $app->view()->getData('user'))]);
});
```

to render users. I use `$authenticate` to check user login, which is as follows:

```
$authenticate = function ($app) use ($secretshibe) {
  return function () use ($app, $secretshibe) {
    if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
      $_SESSION['urlRedirect'] = $app->request()->getPathInfo();
      $app->flash('error', 'Please login to see that page');
      $app->redirect('/login');
    }
  };
};
```

What I need to do, it have another logic check which checks if the user has paid. That can be obtained from `$secretshibe->check_payment($username)` which returns a bool, so my final function looks like this.

```
$authenticate = function ($app) use ($secretshibe) {
  return function () use ($app, $secretshibe) {
    if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
      $_SESSION['urlRedirect'] = $app->request()->getPathInfo();
      $app->flash('error', 'Please login to see that page');
      $app->redirect('/login');
    }
    if (!$secretshibe->check_payment($_SESSION['user'])) {
      $app->flash('error', 'Your account has been marked as unpaid. Please pay to continue usage.');
      $app->redirect('/manager/payment');
    }
  };
};
```

The problem is that when it redirects to `/manager/payment` it uses the same route function, which checks authentication the same way. This results in the page getting stuck in a redirect loop. In order to stop this, I need to check if the requested route is `/manager/payment` before redirecting.

Because the `$authenticate` function is called as middleware, it is invoked before the route function, meaning that I cannot simply pass `$page` to it. What is the best way to prevent this redirect loop?

Answer (score 2):

You want to register `$authenticate` as a [Hook](http://docs.slimframework.com/#Hooks-Overview) rather than as route Middleware.

`$app->hook('slim.before.dispatch', $authenticate($app));`

Alternately, you could use [custom Middleware](http://docs.slimframework.com/#How-to-Write-Middleware) to register the hook. I've done that in quite a few projects. It might look something like this:

```
class MyMiddleware extends \Slim\Middleware
{
    public function call()
    {
        $app = $this->app;

        $authenticate = function ($app) use ($secretshibe) {
            // ... snip ...
        }

        $app->hook('slim.before.dispatch', $authenticate($app));

        $this->next->call();
    }
}
```

Here's a recent [example](https://github.com/jeremykendall/slim-auth/blob/da26a646327f9d0f499bcfdc4c11b1c5657df03d/src/JeremyKendall/Slim/Auth/Middleware/Authorization.php#L83) of using Middleware to register a hook from one of my personal projects.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you need a closure in your middleware ? you could get app form `\Slim\Slim::getInstance()`.

Also route middleware passed one argument, the matching route.

```
$authenticate = function ($route) use ($secretshibe) {
    // get the app instance
    $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();

    if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
      $_SESSION['urlRedirect'] = $app->request()->getPathInfo();
      $app->flash('error', 'Please login to see that page');
      $app->redirect('/login');
    }

    if ($route->getName() !== '/manager/payment' && !$secretshibe->check_payment($_SESSION['user'])) {
      $app->flash('error', 'Your account has been marked as unpaid. Please pay to continue usage.');
      $app->redirect('/manager/payment');
    }
};

$app->get('/manager/:page', $authenticate, function ($page) use ($app, $secretshibe) {
  $app->render('manager/pages/' . $page . '.php', ['user' => $secretshibe->get_page($page, $app->view()->getData('user'))]);
});
```